# easy-menu primary menu separator problem

Tags: keymap, menu-bar, easy-menu

I really like easy-menu but have discovered an item separator problem; a minimum working example is given below.  When I hybrid `define-key-after` with `easy-menu-add-item`, the item separators in the "Words and Lines" submenu are fine.  However in the primary menu, "My-XEditing", the second item separator is missing.

Apparently, using this approach, easy-menu will only allow one item separator in the primary menu.  Since this is the only easy-menu problem that I have, I want to avoid having to delve through elisp (keymaps).  My guess is that a workaround might be found by grafting on `easy-menu-define`, but I can't figure out how.

```lisp
(define-key-after global-map [menu-bar my-xediting]
    (cons "My-XEditing" (make-sparse-keymap "My-XEditing")))
(easy-menu-add-item nil '("My-XEditing") 
    ["Move Character Forward" forward-char t])
(easy-menu-add-item nil '("My-XEditing") "--")
(easy-menu-add-item nil '("My-XEditing") 
    ["Move Character Backward" backward-char t])
(easy-menu-add-item nil '("My-XEditing") "--")
(easy-menu-add-item nil '("My-XEditing")
    (easy-menu-create-menu "Words and Lines"
        '(["Move Word Backward" backward-word t]
        "--"
        ["Move Word Forward" forward-word t]
        "--"
        ["Move Line Backward" previous-line t]
        "--"
        ["Move Line Forward" next-line t])))
```